# How are network switches configured remotely when they have no IP address?

Tags: networking, switch

A network admin can configure a network switch by connecting devices like a keyboard and a monitor to it directly using physical ports available on the switch. Like routers i think the option of copying another switch's configs automatically is available too, but what if network admin needs to connect to switch remotely and make some configuration changes?

Network switches work in MAC layer below Network(IP) layer, so they don't have IP addresses, how remote connection and configuration is possible?

Comment: most of my managed switches do in fact have an ip address, and I use it when accessing the management console. Just because a switch is a layer 2 device doesn't mean it doesn't have features that use layer 3. VLAN trunking is one example of a common switch feature that relies on layer 3 operations to work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switches of course work on MAC layer, but it does not mean, that it can't have IP address. Managed switches have support for IP communication, especially for remote configuration. If the IP is not configured, the only option is some serial communication (ex. RS232).

Comment: +1 to this. A managed switch can have an IP address (lots do) and lots can be configured to also tie a domain to it for true remote access. This is because a switch isn't necessarily in the same location as the network admin and/or might not be feasibly accessed by console cable and computer.